# Pagespeed JS minifier not always work

Tags: nginx, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I'm trying to make pagespeed module to work as expected, but the trouble is - some scripts get minified but some scripts are ingored...

I pack TWO scripts in one by nginx echo module

```
 /location total.js {
    echo_location 'first.js';
    echo_location 'second.js';
 }

 /location terminal.js {
    echo_location 'first_terminal.js';
    echo_location 'second_terminal.js';
 }
```

Then I'm trying to minify them:

```
pagespeed On;
pagespeed UseExperimentalJsMinifier on;
pagespeed FileCachePath /dev/shm/pageSpeedCache;
pagespeed EnableFilters   rewrite_javascript,combine_css,combine_javascript,fallback_rewrite_css_urls,collapse_whitespace;
```

First script comes from nginx Minified but second is **not** Minified. Nothng in nginx.error.log

**What can stop pagespeed from minifying and how should I fix that?**

Answer (score 0):

I found that **UseExperimentalJsMinifier on** feature prevents minifying of large js file wich consists from on single {} object. Turn it off and module will work as expected.